# Происхождение слова "кустарь"

Tags: этимология

Интересно, от какого слова произошло слово "кустарь" (самоучка, мастер народного промысла)? Напрашивается "куст", но при чем тут он?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исследуем вопрос по русским словарям и отечественной литературе. В САР 1789-1794 кустарного дела нет, только обычные кусты и кустарники, да куделя еще есть; всяких там кунстлеров - нету, язык себе не засоряют.  В Словаре 1847 читаем :

> **Кустарникъ** (обл.) - мелкий фабрикантъ, раздающий шерсть или хлопчатую бумагу для обработки **по деревням**...
>
> **Кустарный** - сделанный без особого старания, дюжинный, обракованный (кустарная работа)...
>
> **Кустарь** - то же, что *кустарникъ* {кусты}. "И отделили лесу кустарю 3 десятинъ"...

Кустарщина - это не искусство, а дешевые поделки. Корень *куст* может означать разбросанность работников по своим домам, без централизации производства. Может, есть и другой подсмысл.

Берем словарь **немецкий** :

> **кустарь** сущ. фразы |  g-sort 
>   общ.      Handwerksmeister m; Hausgewerbetreibende; Kleingewerbetreibende; Heimhandwerker m
>   бизн.     Heimwerker m
>   экон.     Handwerker m; Heimarbeiter m; Kleingewerbetreibender; Hausarbeiter m
>   юр.   Heimgewerbebetreibender n (род неправ. Heimgewerbebetreibender m Rusudan); **Kustar** m

http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=3&l2=2&s=%EA%F3%F1%F2%E0%F0%FC

Последний вариант перевода - **KUSTAR** - не является ли заимствованием **из русского языка**??? ...

~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Вслед за Востоковым заслушаем другого титана русского словарного дела, В.И.Даля :

> **Куст** ... {далее - производные} :
>
> **Кустарник** ...
>
> || Моск. влад. мелкий, фабричный
> промышленник, ткач бумажных и шелковых
> тканей, работающий дома на один стан; также
> барышник, раздающий этим рабочим припас,
> для работ.
>
> **Кустарь** м. моск. промышленник кустарник.
> Нас кустари одолели, говорят фабриканты.
>
> Кустовой , кустарный, к кусту относящийся,
> кустом растущий...
>
> **Кустарный промысел**, кустарничество ср.
> моск. дело мелочного, одиночного ткача;
> кустарничать, заниматься, промышлять этим,
> как большей частью Богородского уезда.
> **Кустарное изделие**, работа кустарника, **самый
> плохой и дешевый товар**, с виду похожий на
> фабричный, и потому сбивающий цену.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

**Мнение профессора П.Я.Черных** по ссылке :

http://slovari.ru/default.aspx?p=1017

Вопрос : Какова этимология слова "кустарь" ? 
Ответ: Происхождение слова кустарь не совсем ясно. Сначала ему, по-видимому, предшествовало слово "кустарник". Фасмер связывает его с нем. Kunstler "художник", "артист" и со ср.-н.-нем. kunster "знаток искусства, ремесла". Но П. Я. Черных утверждает, что кустарник < кустарь - новое слово и в литературный язык попало из говоров, из просторечия. Это слово происходит, очевидно, от прил. кустарный (ср. кустарное ремесло) в значении "сделанный без старания". "Старшее" значение слова кустарник могло быть близким к халтурщик (например, "занимающийся своим ремеслом где-нибудь на отлете "в кустах"). Ср. у Даля, который решительно относил кустарник, кустарь к гнезду слова куст, сибирское кустарник "бродяга, который прячется в лесу по кустам" (справка дана по кн. П. Я. Черных. Историко-этимологический словарь современного русского языка. М., 1993. Т. 1. С. 459).

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

**Ф.В.Булгарин, Воспоминания (1846-1849)**

> В то время русская фабричная и мануфактурная промышленность была в самом плохом состоянии, так сказать, в колыбели. **В России изготовлялись только изделия для употребления простого народа**. Поместное дворянство, чиновники и достаточные купцы употребляли товары английские и отчасти французские. Ни один порядочный человек не носил платья из русского сукна, и ни одна женщина из образованного сословия не могла, хотя бы и желала, употребить русские изделия для своих нарядов. **Русское изделие и дурное изделие были синонимы, и притом по всей справедливости.** Все изделия английских фабрик и мануфактур были чрезвычайно дешевы, гораздо дешевле и лучше даже нынешних русских изделий, которые мы хвалим теперь отчасти потому, что некоторые из этих изделий точно хороши, а более восхваляем из патриотизма. Главный недостаток русской фабричной промышленности был, есть и будет тот, что фабрики наши по мелочному расчету **пускают в продажу брак*** {см. сноску},  вместе с хорошим товаром, когда, напротив, в Англии все произведения одной фабрики равного достоинства.

---

> - Для этого в **русском торговом языке** существует особое название: ***кустарные произведения***. Это то же, что дюжинная работа.

Старорежимные этимологи продолжают впаривать студентам немецких кЮНстЛеров. Хотя сами немцы заимствовали русское слово *кустарь* в качестве юридического термина - *Kustar*. Видимо, их смутили непреодолимые фонетические и исторические трудности, о которых говорил Черных, и они не стали вспоминать своих **искусников-художников**. Кустарь - он и в Германии kustar.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

С превеликим трудом и старанием добрались мы с вами до версий, которые никто и никогда не озвучивал (?)

Давайте отбросим подальше немецкое понятие Kunst и вспомним родное **Искусство**!

> ИСКУССТВО (**из-**, **-куст-**), а, ср. □ им. мн. -а и -ы. 1. обычно ед. **Умение, мастерство**, приобретенное изучением, опытом. (ФЭБ, Словарь РЯ 18 века)

Кто не согласен считать  *искуство* (так раньше писали) и *искусников* причастными к кустарным владимирско-московским "мануфактурным" народным промыслам, может вспомнить общеславянский глагол ***kustriti/kustrati** - трепать, взлохмачивать (например, волосы или лен, коноплю, пеньку для пряжи).

А и взаправду, взлохмаченная голова или кудель для пряжи напоминают раскидистый кустарник.
[image: Кудель]

**Куд**ель = **куст** (переход Д-СТ, если кто забыл))) Кудлатые брови = кустистые брови. **Куст**арь - **куд**ельник (ница).

Дополнительное соображение. Прилагательное *кустарный* в значении "рукодельный" впервые в русской литературе зафиксировано Нацкорпусом у того же Булгарина, в 1843 г. :

> Ф.В. Булгарин. Гостиный двор (1843) Слово рынок в гостинодворском языке есть нечто унизительное: товар рыночный, **товар кустарный** ― значит, или товар плохой отделки, или порченый, или вышедший из обыкновенной продажи.

Вот когда возник термин (кустарный товар) - в начале 1840-х годов! Слово *кустарь* в значении "мелкий производитель" находится гораздо позже, в 1871 г. :

> П. И. Мельников-Печерский. В лесах. (1871-1874) ― Не фабрики, кустарей по какому ни на есть промыслу разводить ― вот что надо, ― сказал Василий Борисыч.

Кустарный - впервые в Словаре 1847, наряду с кустарником-фабрикантом. В каком году Даль вставил в свой словарь кустаря-промышленника - хороший вопрос. Все смысло- и словоизменения происходили постепенно и хорошо прослеживаются; внебрачных связей с немецкими умельцами не обнаружено, вопрос закрыт.

Вместо простого ответа получилось целое исследование! Оно того стоило. А *кунстеров* фасмеровских - в паровозную топку братьев Черепановых!)))

Comment: это с каких пор искусство от куста?
искус иску́с иску́сный, искуси́ть, укр. куси́ти "испытывать", ст.-слав. искоусити πειράζειν, δοκιμάζειν. От куси́ть, праслав. *kusiti, заимств. из гот. kausjan "γεύεσθαι, δοκιμάζειν"; см. Бернекер 1, 652 и сл. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1977
А есть еще продолжение  вкус, вкушать, кусать.
искусство оттуда с добавлением корня(суффикс ство--от сотворить)
немецкое KUNst  точно не при чем, корень интересный, в арабском فن-хан. в других языках ART, а пушка везде практически  GUN.

Comment: переход ст-д  это загиб тот еще, кустель получается, и соответственно---насвиСТель автор подобного перехода.
Тем не менее промышленник от промысла. От использования мысли в деле. И куст не случайно, а достаточно близко к плетению изделий из прутьев кустов ивы. Очень распространенный практически в каждой русской деревне чисто ручной и индивидуальный промысел.
Кустарь - одиночка.
Каких только шедевров не делал.

Comment: да и лен с коноплей для получения кудели  не кустрят, а кострят, освобождают от костры-стружки, которую после трепания в костер. так что вся это ИЕ реконструкция ( общеславянский глагол *kustriti/kustrati - трепать, взлохмачивать (например, волосы или лен, коноплю, пеньку для пряжи)) вместе с фасмеровскими этимологиями, по большей части,туда же не грех послать.
И оно понятно, рукоделье-кустарное, оно барину зачем корзина или лапти с рынка, в гостином дворе в начале 19 века торговали исключительно фабричным товаром, по большей части, импортного производства. а рынок был на сенной площади.

Comment: да и кстати, кудель больше ассоциируется не с кустом, а именно с руКОДЕЛЬем.

Comment: Поскольку алдминистрация считает, что характеристика "ахинея" обижает автора и рекомендует пользоваться кнопкой минус, мне ничего не остается, как воспользоваться этим советом.

Answer (score 6):

Это слово имеет немецкие корни: Kunstler (образовано от Kunst – "искусство"; вспомним открытую Петром I в Петербурге кунсткамеру) по-немецки означает "художник", "артист".

Answer (score 0):

Кустом вообще-то называлась маленькая "ячейка" кустарных объединений, часто - семейная. 
Но скорее всего это вторичное, т.е. связанная с переосмыслением. Сейчас это значение почти полностью забыто.

Я все-таки за немецкую версию.

Comment: Удивительно, кому надо было минусовать вполне нейтральную версию - тем более не мою! - в давно забытом вопросе... Для многочисленных новорожденных мультов и клонов повторяю. Смысл минуса не в том, чтобы сделать гадость, а в том чтобы объяснить неправильность каких-то положений в тексте. Без внятного комментария эта кнопка бессмысленна.    
А, понятно. @fatyalink резвится.  
http://russ.hashcode.ru/users/1931/fatyalink/reputation/    
Поймите же наконец, что здесь нет ничего тайного, только обычно время жалко на ерунду тратить. Но если постараться, ваша визитка остается везде, где вы отметилис

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, "кустарь" обращается в своей работе к устью, источнику ремесла, как и "куст" похож на реку, которая разветвляется от "устья" (корня),как и "уста", источник устной речи, принимающий пищу и воду, как река устьем влагу от ледников и родников.
 "Устаревший" роднится с этими словами корнем "СТ".

Answer (score 0):

Возможно это все-же англицизм. В конце первой четверти 19-го века (около 1830 г) в английских словарях появилось достаточно близкое по смыслу и написанию слово "custom" - "сделанное по индивидуальной мерке или на заказ". Оно, в свою очередь, имеет в основе еще более древний (рубеж 12 и 13 веков) термин "custom" (обычай, традиция), заимствованный из старофранцузского (costume - "обычай, привычка, практика; одежда, платье") или латыни (consuetumen (вульг.), consuetudinem (consuetudo) -  "привычка, использование, путь, практика, традиция").

Answer (score 0):

Любопытно, что английское bushcraft, означающее "навыки выживания в естественной среде", т.е. чем-то близкое по смыслу к "кустарным" умениям, содержит корень bush, т.е. "куст".